# Post to nested array in db by ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My client is sending two variables to my server in an object:

```
{ status: "Y", guest: "123xyz" }
```

I would like to take the "Y" and push it to my database using the guest variable to find the proper ObjectID from my database (they match in most cases).

My challenge is the "guests" array is nested inside the model, so I'm trying to query it out then push my req.body.status variable onto the ObjectID. Here's the db model:

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  address: String,
  description: String,
  guests: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      attended: String // this will be the "Y" from the client
    }
  ],
});
```

Here's my function:

```
module.exports.checkIn = async(req, res) => {
    const guest = Event.findOne({ 'guests.ObjectId': req.body.guest });
    guest.push(req.body.status);
    await guest.save();
}
```

I've been reviewing these [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) (which are helpful) but I'm receiving error "TypeError: guest.push is not a function".

I can follow docs or videos I'm just having trouble conceptually what I'm missing. Could you help me understand this better?

Comment: You're trying to push the status to *where*? You find an event by its participant (the variable is called "guest" for some reason, even though it's an Event). What would you like to do with the status? Should the Event's status be updated?

Comment: Hi @RobertKawecki - I'm trying to push the status to my guests array within the Event model. I'd like the "status" to update the 'attended' field to "Y".

Ie., { attended: "Y" } 

That way I can see how many guests showed up to an event.

Comment: The first issue is that the `findOne` method has a _filter_ which s not correctly formed. See how to [query an array of embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

Comment: Hi @prasad_ - thanks for the comment. The link you send is for the database syntax.. my understanding was that the db syntax didn't work through mongoose (basically I can only use it in the terminal) and I have to use the mongoose functions from the app. Is that not the case?

Comment: It is not correct to think that the native query syntax wont work with NodeJS/Mongoose queries - most of the time they are similar (or even same). Mongoose has various syntax for single operation - so one needs to figure / try. I am sure there are posts or examples online to write that kind of query.

Comment: The db language hasn't worked for me so not sure how accurate your response is.